# SSRS: code function to sanitise HTML for rendering in RDLC report

Tags: html, .net, regex, vb.net

**Background**

I have an RDLC that among other things displays text coming in that is captured in SharePoint, using a custom control (TinyMCE) that exposes limited formatting options to users.

The SSRS local report renderer supports a subset of HTML (see details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff519562(v=sql.105).aspx)) and has limited configurability. It has some rendering behaviours that need to be worked around (e.g. if there are `<p>` tags, it adds some vertical padding above and below the text in the report). I am targeting PDF for reports.

**Purpose**

Below is a function that I have embedded in the RDLC to accept a string (an HTML fragment in most cases), do the following, and return the transformed string for use in a text field within the report:

- Convert to ASCII (if I don't do this, sometimes the first line of text appears with no spaces)
- Do some replacement of tags as detailed in code comments
- Decode HTML character entities

**Concerns**

- Performance is my main concern at this point.
- I suspect the regexes are overkill, certainly from a performance perspective. I've read a bit about backtracking issues but not sure if this code is subject to it.
- I am **not concerned** about the suitability of regex to parse HTML in this case, as it will always be well-formed. I'm aware of the normal wise counsel around doing this in general cases.

```
Public Function HTMLHelper(input As String) As String

Dim r As String = ""

If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) = False Then
    ' transform string to Ascii encoding (addresses problem where the first line rendered to PDF hasnospacesinitatall)
    r = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                       System.Text.Encoding.Convert(
                        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                        System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(
                            System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName,
                            New System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback(String.Empty),
                            New System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback()
                            ),
                        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)))

    ' transformations for tags that are troublesome in SSRS
    r = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(r, "(?i)</?div[^>]*>", "") ' remove DIV tags
    r = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(r, "(?i)<p[^>]*>", "") ' remove opening P tags
    r = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(r, "(?i)</p[^>]*>\s*(?=\Z)", "") ' remove final closing P tag
    r = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(r, "(?i)</p[^>]*>", "<br>") ' replace remaining closing P tags with BR

    ' decode HTML character entities (like "&#58;" resolves to ":")
    r = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(r)
End If

Return r

End Function
```